# How can I combine these columns in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SMSS v17.3

added- select @@version shows "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)   Jun 10 2015 03:35:45   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) "

I have

```
-- Book = book name.
-- Ch=chapter V=verse

CREATE TABLE dbo.flow1(Id int, A varchar(10), B varchar(10), Book varchar(10), Ch INT, V INT)

INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(1, 'qwe', 'asd', 'gggg', 3, 44)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(2, 'qwe', 'asd', 'asdf', 43, 11)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(3, 'erw', 'asd', 'fsef', 12, 53)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(4, 'erw', 'zre', 'vxde', 53, 12)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(5, 'vwe', 'hwa', 'vwhe', 11, 51)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(6, 'rwq', 'yha', 'bgda', 63, 12)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(7, 'qwe', 'asd', 'faaa', 32, 61)
INSERT INTO dbo.flow1 VALUES(8, 'rwq', 'yha', 'fsag', 35, 3)

SELECT A,B,COUNT(Id) as cnt  FROM dbo.flow1 GROUP BY A,B;
```

[image]

What I would like is

[image]

A while back I tried fiddling around with CONCAT to do it, I would include what I tried here but I can't find it, anyhow I never quite managed it at the time.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: @RBarryYoung i'm actually using SQL Studio but I saw no tag for it and I was not aware of any difference.

Comment: @Xedni Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)   Jun 10 2015 03:35:45   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    A,
    B,
    Cnt = count(Id),
    Concatted =
    stuff
        (
            (
                select concat(',', Book, ' ', Ch, ':', V)
                from Flow1 i
                where o.A = i.A
                    and o.B= i.B
                for xml path(''), type
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
            1, 1, ''
        )

from flow1 o
group by A,B
```

Comment: thanks.. btw that got an error but it worked when I changed #flow1 to flow1.  then I got no error. Then for the delimiters `select  concat(',', Book, ' ', Ch, ':', V)`

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. I had thrown your data in a temp table when I was playing around with it. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: interestingly it's very easy to do in MySQL (sqlfiddle here set to mysql),  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7d50/6 `SELECT A,B,COUNT(Id) as cnt,GROUP_CONCAT(Book,' ',Ch,':',V) FROM flow1 GROUP BY A,B` though indeed seems to require quite a bit more in ms sql.

Comment: It looks like there would perhaps be  a way to do this with Coalesce http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2014/10/tip-concatenate-rows-with-xml-or-coalesce/  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929521/in-sql-server-management-studio-sql-server-fails-on-hebrew-diacritical-marks

Comment: @barlop thanks for pointing that out. My main beef with that approach is how much control it (doesn't) give you. You have to concatenate every value returned from your query, and you can't *easily* restart your sequence halfway through. There are also some gotchas with that approach (and, to be fair, with `FOR XML` as well). But as long as you understand what it's doing, that's a perfectly valid approach too. I tend to reach for `FOR XML` because  I think it's a little clearer what's going on, and gives me various options I might want right off the bat.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that with Coalesce,  "You have to concatenate every value returned from your query" ?   I have found that you can pick what columns you want, and you can add a WHERE clause to pick what rows you want.   https://pastebin.com/raw/P8UPrdT5

Comment: I suppose this kind of thing `DECLARE @blah NVARCHAR(4000); 
SELECT @blah = COALESCE(@blah + '', '') + aaa +Convert(NVARCHAR(5),bbb) 
FROM @ppp2 WHERE aaa='tod' OR aaa='phil';

SELECT @blah;   --  tod111phil222`   isn't with a group by though.